# topoJSON for congressional districts

Tags: geojson

Has anyone seen a topoJSON file for U.S. congressional districts? Alternatively, if I can locate the coordinates or a geoJSON file, is it easy to convert to arcs?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Official cartographic boundaries are more likely to be found as shapefiles rather than GeoJSON or TopoJSON, although in this case you can find both in the [jsongeo/cd113](https://github.com/jsongeo/cd113)  repository on GitHub ([cd113.topojson](https://github.com/jsongeo/cd113/raw/master/cd113.topojson)).

To get the data directly from the U.S. Census Bureau, a little Google searching will lead you to [TIGER/Line shapefiles](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html) for the 113th Congress. (Congressional districts change slightly from congress to congress, so be careful that you use the appropriate version!) Clicking through to the “FTP Site Sorted by Layer” you’ll find the cryptically-named [CD113](http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGERrd13/CD113/) folder, and at the very bottom, [tl_rd13_us_cd113.zip](http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGERrd13/CD113/tl_rd13_us_cd113.zip), a 38M zipped shapefile that contains the congressional districts for the entire United States. This file is far to large for you to use directly, but you can follow the [Let’s Make a Map](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) tutorial to use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) and [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) to convert the shapefile to a more manageable representation.

Specifically, you’d start by converting the Shapefile to GeoJSON (101MB!):

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON districts.json tl_rd13_us_cd113.shp
```

Then convert the GeoJSON to TopoJSON and simplify (only 472KB):

```
topojson -s 7e-9 --id-property=+GEOID -o us-congress-113.json -- districts.json
```

Now the first two digits of the geometry id (`d.id / 1000 | 0`) are the state FIPS code (see [us-state-names.tsv](https://gist.github.com/4090846#file-us-state-names-tsv)) and the last two digits are the congressional district number (`d.id % 1000`) within that state. The simplification (`-s`) is optional, but it’s generally a good idea if you’re displaying a static map in a browser; I tuned the threshold to retain about half the points, but you could make the file even smaller by using a larger threshold.

And there you have it:

[image: 113th U.S. Congressional Districts]

You’ll probably want to combine the TopoJSON file with the *land* and *states* features from [us.json](https://gist.github.com/4090846#file-us-json), since in most maps you’ll want to clip the congressional districts to the land boundary, and draw some additional boundary between states. That can be done by combining TopoJSON files using multiple input arguments to the topojson binary.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! I needed 2008 boundaries, so thanks for teaching a man to fish.

Comment: Is there a way to combine the districts TopoJSON file with this state names file  https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4090846/raw/d534aba169207548a8a3d670c9c2cc719ff05c47/us-state-names.tsv  to create propertys displaying which state each district belongs to in the main TopoJSON file?  Complete Datamaps noob here

Comment: Do you have any advice on finding/generating a new map for the 116th Congress? All I can find is an [SVG map](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:116th_U.S._Congress_House_districts.svg) and a few search results with geographic data I can't really figure out how to export. The [Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_cds.html) doesn't appear to have shapefiles for the 116th yet.

Answer (score 2):

Another great resource for this is the united states github repo:

https://github.com/unitedstates/districts

The repository has both kml and geojson files for each congressional district, in separate folders by date.

Answer (score 1):

This Census Bureau link will introduce and direct you to shapefiles for the data you're looking for:

http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/

shapefiles can be converted to geojson and topojson files. here's a basic tutorial that will introduce you to many of considerations:

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/

Answer (score 0):

I made this dataset and adaptated projection for d3 v4, maybe it suits your needs:

http://bl.ocks.org/rveciana/fe6b452c853146e674dd6dd09c1cc6e3[image]